# Firebase query like WHERE clause of sql

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working with `Firebase` in Android. In my app, there is a scenario where I need to fetch the filtered list from root node on basis of a field which is inside its child. For more clearance on problem see the sample database structure below.

[image]

For example, I need to fetch from Root `Chats` where part contains 3 as value. I have tried [Firebase Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) but not helpful. Is there a way to get the filtered list as above?

Comment: Where part contains 3 childrens or one of the part's childrens has `3` as a value?

Comment: its probably better if you change the structure of the database

Comment: you should use firebase's structure for realtime-database chats to make a working chatroom with easy querying. anyway, i recomend switching to firebase firestore that does have a quite better querying system that might satisfy you.

Comment: Where part contain 3 as a value.

Comment: its really better if you change the structure, as if you only have the child("chats") then it will be a complex query or it wont even work. But if you have other childrens avaliable then it can work

Comment: So i guess there is no way to perform such query . Can you please provide some link or reference for a better ChatModule database structure which i can follow .

Comment: I suggest you change your structure that part will be string of values separated  by comma then you can do something like this `databaseReference.orderByChild('part').startAt("3").endAt("3"+"\uf8ff").once("value")`

Comment: why is there "0" and "1" under the parts anyway? What is the parts also?

Comment: parts is an Array thats why there is indexing as 0,1... .

Comment: This is a categorization problem, which indeed can't be solved with your current data structure. Have a look at my explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Answer (score 2):

You cannot query your database as mentioned in your question using the actual database structure. In such cases, there is a practice named `denormalization` and for that I recomend you see this video, [Denormalization is normal with the Firebase Database](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vKqXSZLLnHA).

In your case, you need to get the `part` node out from chat node and create a new top level node in which you can store those values. I recomend you also use as the name of the child, the exact name that you want to query. In this case you will be able to attach a listener on that particular node and use `exists()` method to check a child for existens.

In also recomend you read this post, [Structuring your Firebase Data correctly for a Complex App](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data) for a better understanding.

There are two more resourses that I want to share, [The Firebase Database For SQL Developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s) and [NoSQL Data Modeling Techniques](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("databaseData").equalTo("yourdatayouwant");
```

You can do that with this way

Comment: I guess not `equalTo` can work with single value type . But As i mentioned in question parts is an array so you can not perform `equalTo` on an array .